# How to check if a NMR endpoint exists in servicemix?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I use dynamic routing my integration project, which may be multiple camel contexts. 
I can see if there is an endpoint in one camel context:

```
getContext.hasEndpoint("nmr:targetEndpoint")!=null
```

But it does not work if the endpoint is in another camel context...

Comment: Maybe you can look in JMX to see if SMX have registered an nmr endpoint. Or look at SMX API what it offers you can use.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api.event.EndpointListener` see http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.5.x/nmr/nmr-event-listeners.html